# what functions can be used on a NAMED RANGE when being used for a chart

Tags: excel, charts, named-ranges

i have previoulsy used OFFSET to create a dynamic Named Range, 
and then used it on a chart,

However, I also have the below to define a named range:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(0,ProFormaCheck!$C$5:$C$108,1)+5,3)&":"&ADDRESS(MATCH(0,ProFormaCheck!$C$5:$C$108,1)+4+COUNTIF(ProFormaCheck!$C$5:$C$108,">"&0),3))
```

I can use this named range in a formula, but if i try to use it within a chart my computer freezes each time

Is it only specific functions that can be used within a Named Range being used on a chart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not got a full answer to my question,

But i changed the formula for the named range to

```
=OFFSET($C$5,MATCH($A$1,$B$5:$B$108,0)-COUNTIF($C$5:$C$108,">"&0)-1,0,COUNTIF($C$5:$C$108,">"&0),1)
```

and it now works in my chart,
so the chart must not like named ranges that contain either:

ADDRESS

or INDIRECT